# Techniques to check if a surface is regular

Tags: differential-geometry

This is (a part) of exercise $7c$ page $66$ of DoCarmo's book (Differential geometry of curves and surfaces).

Let $f(x,y,z)=xyz^{2}$. I'm trying to figure out if the preimage of $f$ under $0$ is a regular surface.

Basically the preimage is the union of the three coordinate planes in the $xyz$ plane but how can we prove that there exists a point in where regularity fails?

I don't see this very clear. Can you please help?

Comment: the preimage is a regular surface iff the point is regular (by the implicit function theorem).

Answer (score 6):

This exercise asks you for map $$f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:\,f(x,y,z)=xyz^{2}$$ 
(a) find the critical points and  the critical values,

(b) and tell for what values $c$ the set $f(x,y,z)=c$ is a regular surface.

Definition 2 on p. 58 of the book tells you that in order to enumerate all the critical points you need to examine the differential map $df$ which can be represented by a matrix as $$
(f_x,f_y,f_x)=(y z^2,x z^2, 2 x y z)$$
Now you can see that $df:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not surjective iff $(y z^2,x z^2, 2 x y z)=(0,0,0)$, so we can write down the set of critical points as
$$
\mathcal{K}=\{(x,y,x) \in \mathbb{R}^3|z=0 \text{ OR } (x=o \text{ AND } y=0)\}
$$

You can see immediately that the only critical value is $0=f(\mathcal{K})$.

In other words, the regularity fails in the standard way: "the derivative is zero."

This solves part (a).

---

As for part (b), you now need to argue that the set that you described in your question is not the graph of any function as Proposition 3 on p. 63 of the book suggests. For that it is enough to examine three cases, as shown in this Proposition: $z=f(x,y), y=g(x,z), x=h(y,z)$. It is easy to see that your set cannot be of any of these forms.

A confusion may occur due to an identification of the tangent spaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$ (I hope you can see where this happens in the above).

Proposition 2, p. 59, ibid., tells you that all other points will be regular.

Hopefully, this helps.

(**Edited** to add the correct demonstration of part (b)).

Comment: thanks, sorry but I don't get the line "the regularity fails in the standard way: the derivative is zero" is this a theorem? Can you please explain more?

Comment: By definition, regular points are those that are not critical, whence by critical points we understand points at which the differential is not invertible. The last condition is a generalization of "the derivative is not zero" in one-dimensional case. I meant that.

Comment: to show $f^{-1}(0)$ is not a regular surface we need to show that the definition of regular surface fails, which is this definition: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularSurface.html , why what you wrote implies that for every open set $W \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ containing the preimage of $0$ we cannot find an open set of the plane $U$ and a diffeomorphsim $U \rightarrow W \cap S$? I don't see it. In this case $S=f^{-1}(0)$

Comment: Ah, thanks, I see your point. What you a referring to is basically the same as Definition 1, p. 52, of the book. I think it is sufficient to use Proposition 3 in this case. Otherwise we would have to cite the entire chapter. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Yuri, not *surjective*, it may very well be not invertible (e.g. with Morse functions).

Comment: @Alexei, we talk about a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ here, how can it be *invertible*? In general, regularity implies maximal rank which is equivalent to surjectivity in this case.

Comment: @Yuri, that's exactly what I meant, I was correcting your earlier comment: "by critical points we understand points at which the differential is not invertible".

Comment: You are right, @Alexei, I was a little sloppy there

Comment: @Yuri no problems :)